# How to change perpage in laravel 10.x paginate

Tags: php, laravel

i can specify how many records to return on per page with the code :

```
$payments = Payment::paginate(10);
```

or, for example, i can do the same for users with the following code :

```
$users = User::paginate(10);
```

if tomorrow i want to change the number 10 to 50, a disaster will happen

how can i change this number globally in setting? (the more flexible and better structured the code is, the happier i am :) )

i had many attempts

like creating `pagination.php` file  in path `app/config` with the following content :

```
<?php

return [
    'per_page' => 1,
];
```

or change file `AppServiceProvider.php` to following content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Paginator::perPage(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `limit` instead of `per_page` in the config?

Comment: @RAZIUL I tried It was useless

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to globally set the pagination number. Just creating a config setting without doing anything else does not work, as you noticed.

However, if you create a new config file called `config/pagination.php` with the following:

```
<?php

return [
    'per_page' => 1,
];
```

Then, you can use the following:

```
$payments = Payment::paginate(config('pagination.per_page'));
$users = User::paginate(config('pagination.per_page'));
```

This allows you to globally set the pagination count!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `.env` variable for per page value and update it whenever you want.
Firstly, create a `pagination.php` file in the config directory:

```
return [
    'per_page' => env('PAGINATION_PER_PAGE', 15),
];
```

usage of it:

```
$payments = Payment::paginate(config('pagination.per_page'));
$users = User::paginate(config('pagination.per_page'));
```

in the `.env`:

```
PAGINATION_PER_PAGE=10
```

don't forget to run `php artisan config:clear` for clearing caches.

And you can simply change this variable by code: `config(['pagination.per_page' => 50]);`